# sending json data to php not working

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to send my rebuilt json data to my php script to php. but the json data sending and receiving not working. its returning "NULL". Please tell me how to send and retrieve my premade json data via ajax. what wrong with my code.

**Jquery Script**

```
var jsonObj = [];
var obj = {};
obj["medicine_name"]=parsed.medicine_name;
obj["quantity"]=unit;
obj["price"]=price;
jsonObj.push(obj);
console.log(jsonObj);
$("#order").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
//$jsonObj=JSON.stringify(jsonObj)
$.ajax({
url: "../siddiqa/function/ordermedicine.php",
type: "POST",
//dataType: "json",
data: jsonObj,
success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
        alert(data);

        },
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            //if fails   

        }
})


})
```

**PHP script**

```
<?php
require_once('../configuration.php');
$con=new mysqli($hostname,$dbusername,$dbpass,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    die('The connection to the database could not be established.');
}
$obj = $_POST['jsonObj'];

var_dump($obj)


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is really a json data as your question says

> sending json data to php not working

You need to uncomment this line for sending json data and this answer to work

```
 $jsonObj=JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
```

Now ,Since it is json data that is being sent in php you cant get it by simple $_POST you need to do this kind of stuff to get this posted data

```
$data=file_get_contents('php://input');
$dataobj= json_decode($data);
```

Here you get data first then decode it from json to normal object

Comment: He never called `JSON.stringify()` in the Javascript, so it won't be sent as JSON.

Comment: $jsonObj=JSON.stringify(jsonObj); and sending json data to php not working

Comment: @Barmar title was this and a line was also commented so i provided solution according to the title

Comment: You've been here long enough that you should know that 99% of the time when someone says "JSON object", they mean "Javascript object".

Comment: yes @barmar but JSON object and that un commented line makes me to thnk he want json. and so you have provided good answer with regular object so i answered the actual title :)

Comment: Ahh, I didn't notice the commented line. I don't know why he thinks he needs JSON, x-www-form-urlencoded is just as good.

Comment: @Barmar you are senior in experience and seniors dont notice these un neccesary thing , but i just thought it can be a possible solution:)

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP expects a parameter with a key `jsonObj`, but `jsonObj` is an array, so it doesn't have any named keys. It should be:

```
var jsonObj = {};
var obj = {};
obj.medicine_name=parsed.medicine_name;
obj.quantity=unit;
obj.price=price;
jsonObj.jsonObj = obj;
```

I'm not really sure why you're nesting the objects like this. You could just do:

```
data: obj
```

and then in the PHP script you can access `$_POST['medicine_name']`, `$_POST['quantity']`, and `$_POST['price']`.